# The way of iterating through the node in SinglyLinkedList

Tags: java, iteration

I've recently encountered a problem of iterating through the node from head to tail.

I usually used this method to iterate:

```
Node<E> walk = head;
while (walk != null) {
    //do the job
    walk = walk.getNext();
}
```

but when I tried to use for-loop instead, I got a null pointer error

```
for (Node<E> walk = head; walk.next != null; walk = walk.next) {
    //do the job
}
```

Do I only have to use while-loop to iterate through the node? Or is it just my code making a bug because of my mistake?

Also, what makes a difference between walk.next and walk.getNext? I thought they are the same things

here is a getNext method

```
public Node<E> getNext() { return next; }
```

Comment: Have you considered the case where `head` is null? What does `walk.next` do in this case?

Comment: Umm. head wasn't empty because the above one works fine. and walk.next is like a pointer that instructs to go to the next node

Comment: here is my code for next - private Node<E> next;         // reference to the subsequent node in the list

Comment: Just a quick hint: Make `head` a pseudo node that's never null and you'll greatly simplify your whole implementation a great deal.

Comment: @Voo So there is nothing wrong with my for-loop code? right?

Comment: No - your termination clause should be `walk != null`

Comment: What Node class is that? If its your own, can you provide some basic code for it. From the looks of it right now, next is pushing the iterator forward, so you're actually moving the iterator forward twice on every `for` loop iteration, which could cause null pointer error.

Comment: @shot Oh there is, otherwise you wouldn't get an exception. But you will simplify your code a great deal if you try it with a pseudo node. Lots of special cases fall away and are handled naturally.

Comment: *difference between walk.next and walk.getNext* - with `walk.next` you access the variable `next` of the object `walk`. With `walk.getNext()` you call the method `getNext()` on the object `walk`. A method is a totally different concept, compared to variables. In your specific situation the method just returns the object so both statements essentially do the same. However the method could do more and in general it would be preferred to access all members via methods (getter and setter concept), it is way more flexible, and to make all members `private` such that they can't be accessed that way.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I fully understood what I did wrong on the for-loop line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code should work because in your code you are iterating till `walk==null`
that is the reason you are getting `null`  when accessing `walk.next` means `null.next` so Please follow below code.Hope it helps.

```
for (Node<E> walk = head; walk != null; walk = walk.next) {
    //do the job
}
```